# VBA not assigning object to variable

Tags: vba, ms-access, wine

I am, perhaps foolishly, running an old and complex MDB (originally written in Access 2003, where everything worked smoothly for about a decade under good old XP) with lots of VBA in Access 2013 under WINE (well, Crossover Linux). Most things work, surprisingly, but I have a strange problem with automation. The following code launches an instance of Word that can be seen in task manager, but doesn't assign any object to oWord. It fails at oWord.Visible=True with error 91 and oWord is Nothing.

```
Dim oWord As Word.Application
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True
```

I've tried early binding and late binding and more or less every line of code that can possibly be used to start Word. Using New Word.Application (or New anything) instantly crashes Access and WiNE's crash report is beyond me. I have exactly the same problem with automating Adobe Acrobat Pro, so this isn't about Office: Acrobat starts, but no object is assigned and I get error 91. Both programs launch happily from Shell. CreateObject is not always failing, either: oddly elsewhere in the database I have no problems with

```
Dim HttpReq As Object
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
```

(but it fails without the version number).

I don't think this is to do with references, either, though I can list them if anyone thinks it's worth it.

Sorry this post is all over the place, but, to summarise.

I think my problem is probably with one of the dlls that WINE uses, and the advice I want is about which dll is likely to cause these particular problems if it is corrupt or incorrect. Then I can try different versions, maybe extract a clean copy from a Win 7 ISO (I've tried several copies of oleaut32.dll, which can be a sore subject with WINE, to no effect save that you can't run VBA at all with WINE's builtin version). I don't want to reinstall Office 2013 because it's so twitchy about activation under WINE. I don't want to risk blowing a perfectly valid licence testing it in a new wineprefix/bottle. I have a separate installation on a second workstation that's doing exactly the same thing. I'm running Lubuntu 18.04 LTS with WINE 3.0.5 and Crossover Linux 18; the wineprefixes are emulating Win 7.

Any help would be very, very gratefully received. I know this is a quixotic project, but so much works perfectly that this is really frustrating. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you have encountered a limitation of Wine. Try running the application in native Windows 7. Could be a virtual machine.

Comment: I already have VMs that run my MDB perfectly in XP. Win 7 would only buy me a year or so until end-of-life. I want to move away from Windows completely. The received wisdom is that you can't run Access with VBA under Wine at all, but that's not true. Basically this is the only problem I've come across, and it seems finite and soluble by someone who knows more than me, which is why I asked!

Comment: It may be the only problem, but it is a core problem from what I've heard (never used Wine myself). And Windows 7 is not reaching end of life, only end of support which shouldn't scare you when the run the absolutely unsupported Wine/Office combo. If you wish to leave the Windows environment for good, port your applications to a supported package like LibreOffice.

Comment: The code to open Word runs fine and assigns the object properly in Excel VBA in the same Office installation in the same wineprefix. Can't believe I didn't think of trying that before. So this is something to do with Access not Wine (I've tried making the references the same between the two programs but that, so far, isn't helping).

Comment: That may be so. Access has always been the stubborn member of the Office family, indeed when hosted by Wine.

Comment: I'm unusual in finding Access intuitive and powerful, and, despite going on a couple of courses, Excel awkward and fiddly, which is why I didn't think of trying it. I shall try looking into the differences between their VBAs. (You're really keeping me going with this. I had hoped for a quick fix from an expert because I was tired and fed up but now I have something to prove.)

Comment: OK. Please report back in case of success.